# how to declare Provider with a selectable bloc, so re-use the same page with one of several possible blocs

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-provider

I have a page with tabs, but the tabs and some of the content of the starting page differs upon the role of the user. All logic and tab navigation is handled with a bloc specific to the user role.

Now I wonder how I can declare the Provider with multiple blocs, of which only one is selected. Of course I could also use a multiblocprovider, but then I would have all instances simultaneously open. I tried

`BlocProvider<(roleDisplayed == 0 ? FirstBloc : SecondBloc)>` but this throws `The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type'`.

Do you guys have an idea how to declare this?

Answer (score 1):

You have almost the right syntax.  It would be more like this:

```
roleDisplayed == 0 
? BlocProdvider<FirstBloc>()
: BlocProvider<SecondBloc>()
```

note: You can use a switch statement to the same effect.

You can use a method for creating the bloc in a different file and then call it in the UI where you need it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../../bloc/bloc/first_bloc.dart';

class ChooseBloc {
  getBloc(int roleDisplayed, BuildContext context) {
    if (roleDisplayed == 0) {
      final firstBloc = BlocProvider.of<FirstBloc>(context);
      return BlocBuilder(builder: //builder code here);
    }
  }
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: but then I have to repeat the page content for each BlocProvider, right? For example I have a Stack with the page content and my custom tab bar at the bottom. So wouldn't your example look like `BlocProdvider<FirstBloc>(create:..., child:BlocBuilder(..., builder: (...) {Stack(children:[page(), tabBar()]} ) )`?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I have phrased my intent poorly. I was trying in a structure of (1) `Widget build(return: ` -> (2) `BlocProvider<bloc>(child: ` -> (3) `BlocBuilder<bloc, state>( builder: `-> (4) `return Stack();` to have a more or less fixed code for (1) and (4) and to only adapt (2) and (3) to the chosen bloc. Obviously I can put (4) into a separate class and re-use it for any (2&3), but I hoped to have (1) and (4) in the same class. Anyways, many thanks for your help!!! But I guess I rethink my page logic to have a cleaner code.